# Error on start when using Spork and Guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, guard, spork

Here's the problem. When added the `Guard gem` everything was fine when I was calling `Guard`.
When I added `Spork`, I get the following error that doesn't affect testing my tests but it brings it up every time I try to restart Guard.

```
19:01:28 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
19:01:28 - INFO - Starting Spork for RSpec
19:01:28 - ERROR - Guard::Spork failed to achieve its <start>, exception was:
```

> [#5232DAD6505A] ChildProcess::LaunchError: No such file or directory - bundle exec spork -p 8989
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/childprocess-0.3.7/lib/childprocess/unix/fork_exec_process.rb:54:in `launch_process'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/childprocess-0.3.7/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:68:in`start'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-spork-1.2.0/lib/guard/spork/spork_instance.rb:38:in `start'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-spork-1.2.0/lib/guard/spork/runner.rb:33:in`each'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-spork-1.2.0/lib/guard/spork/runner.rb:33:in `launch_sporks'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-spork-1.2.0/lib/guard/spork.rb:21:in`start'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:99:in `block in run_supervised_task'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:97:in`catch'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:97:in `run_supervised_task'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:54:in`block (2 levels) in run'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:175:in `block (3 levels) in scoped_guards'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:174:in`each'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:174:in `block (2 levels) in scoped_guards'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:173:in`catch'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:173:in `block in scoped_guards'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:172:in`each'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:172:in `scoped_guards'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:53:in`block in run'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/lumberjack-1.0.2/lib/lumberjack.rb:27:in `unit_of_work'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/runner.rb:52:in`run'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard.rb:187:in `block in start'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard.rb:363:in`block in within_preserved_state'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] :10:in `synchronize'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard.rb:360:in`within_preserved_state'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard.rb:185:in `start'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/lib/guard/cli.rb:110:in`start'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in`invoke_task'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/thor-0.17.0/lib/thor/base.rb:434:in`start'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/guard-1.6.2/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/guard:19:in`load'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/guard:19:in `<main>'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval'
>   [#5232DAD6505A] /Users/periclestheodorou/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'
>   19:01:28 - INFO - Guard::Spork has just been fired
>   19:01:28 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
>   19:01:28 - INFO - Running all specs
>   No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
>   No examples found.

Finished in 0.0001 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures

**Here's the Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

**spec_helper**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  # Loading more in this block will cause your tests to run faster. However, 
  # if you change any configuration or code from libraries loaded here, you'll
  # need to restart spork for it take effect.
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # == Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end
```

Comment: You haven't provided a lot of information. However, take a look at this rails cast. http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork , follow it step by step, and you should have no problem running Guard with spork.

Comment: What other information do you need? I had a look at the RailsCast; it was more or less based upon it that I added spork and guard

Comment: what do your spec helper look like?

Comment: added the spec_helper in the question

Comment: After adding spork, you ran bundle install? Mind posting your guardfile also

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That’s a [known issue in `guard-spork`](https://github.com/guard/guard-spork/issues/107) and you can either use the previous version of `ChildProcess` by adding:

```
gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
```

To your `Gemfile` or try the guard-spork master branch, which has [fixed the issue](https://github.com/guard/guard-spork/commit/889e2d97b09b330744021b6610318e0b9ebd5779) by adding the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'guard-spork', :github => 'guard/guard-spork'
```

Comment: that's fantastic thank you very much. I ended up using gem 'guard-spork', :github => 'guard/guard-spork'

Comment: Helped me also, on Mac running latest Mountain Lion. Thank you.

Comment: This has been solved on guard-spock 1.4.2, so you can change to gem 'guard-spork', '1.4.2'.

Comment: I updated my gemfile to use `gem 'guard-spork', '1.4.2'` and it fixed the issue. Thanks @leolobato!

Comment: I removed the version (1.2.0) from guard-spork in my Gemfile, ran bundle update which bumped it to version 1.5.0 and solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
bundle exec guard
```

instead of

```
guard
```

fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Updated the Gemfile to 'guard-spork', '1.4.2' and it fixed it for me.