# Trying to undo Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard, spork

I am learning Ruby on Rails with the help of Michael Hartl's tutorial. I start to do [this section](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-guard). I did the add Guard and everything seemed to work fine. I then went ahead to try doing the Spork process and after following all the instructions, when I run `guard' this is what I get:

```
16:57:46 - INFO - Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are running
> [#] `guard` outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free to ignore this
> [#] message. Otherwise, consider using `bundle exec guard` to ensure your
> [#] dependencies are loaded correctly.
> [#] (You can run `guard` with --no-bundler-warning to get rid of this message.)
16:57:46 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
16:57:46 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
16:57:46 - INFO - Running all specs
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `fixture_path=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007fd2eb836b50> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:107:in `configure'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

16:57:49 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
16:57:49 - INFO - Running all specs
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `fixture_path=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007fa9cbc54028> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:107:in `configure'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

16:57:51 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
16:57:51 - INFO - Running all specs
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `fixture_path=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007f9f9a846f20> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:107:in `configure'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/spork-1.0.0rc4/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/siaW/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

16:57:53 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/siaW/Desktop/pwr'
```

I know I did something wrong but as a newbie I can't pinpoint exactly what I did wrong. I did a lot of googling already and check some solutions here on StackOverflow but all efforts have been in vain so far. I just want to undo the Spork process and have everything going fine like before. I think I may have to skip doing Spork because for now it's too advanced for me.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#check and remove below if not relevant
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end



# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

My Guardfile:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme
require 'active_support/inflector'



guard 'rspec', all_after_pass: false do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }


  watch('config/routes.rb')
    # Rails mastering
    watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) do |m|
      ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
       "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
       "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
       (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
                         "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
    end
    watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
      (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
                        "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
    end
    watch(%r{^app/controllers/sessions_controller\.rb$}) do |m|
      "spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"
    end
end


guard 'rspec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end


guard 'rspec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

I also did run this command `bundle exec spork --bootstrap`in the terminal.
And my `spec_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  # Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
  # If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    # ## Mock Framework
    #
    # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
    #
    # config.mock_with :mocha
    # config.mock_with :flexmock
    # config.mock_with :rr

    # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
    # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
    # the seed, which is printed after each run.
    #     --seed 1234
    config.order = "random"
    config.include Capybara::DSL
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.

end

# --- Instructions ---
# Sort the contents of this file into a Spork.prefork and a Spork.each_run
# block.
#
# The Spork.prefork block is run only once when the spork server is started.
# You typically want to place most of your (slow) initializer code in here, in
# particular, require'ing any 3rd-party gems that you don't normally modify
# during development.
#
# The Spork.each_run block is run each time you run your specs.  In case you
# need to load files that tend to change during development, require them here.
# With Rails, your application modules are loaded automatically, so sometimes
# this block can remain empty.
#
# Note: You can modify files loaded *from* the Spork.each_run block without
# restarting the spork server.  However, this file itself will not be reloaded,
# so if you change any of the code inside the each_run block, you still need to
# restart the server.  In general, if you have non-trivial code in this file,
# it's advisable to move it into a separate file so you can easily edit it
# without restarting spork.  (For example, with RSpec, you could move
# non-trivial code into a file spec/support/my_helper.rb, making sure that the
# spec/support/* files are require'd from inside the each_run block.)
#
# Any code that is left outside the two blocks will be run during preforking
# *and* during each_run -- that's probably not what you want.
#
# These instructions should self-destruct in 10 seconds.  If they don't, feel
# free to delete them.




# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Comment: Holy crap. Comment all that Spork & Guard stuff out, and just use raw Rails & RSpec. And how did Rails - the industry's flagship for website development via TDD, get to be such a pain in the butt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/guard/guard-spork/issues/107) - try following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590399/error-on-start-when-using-spork-and-guard)

Answer (score 0):

In the spec_helper.rb file you posted, the text block after

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

is included twice. You have moved that part into the "Spork.prefork do", but is is repeated after the long instruction comment again. Have you accidentially copied instead of cut when moving it?

Try deleting everything from the spec_helper.rb filed after this:

```
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
end
# delete everything from here...
```